# On UPDATE Trigger - Triggered during its own Execution?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following trigger definition

```
PROMPT CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER C_BUSINESS_TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER C_BUSINESS_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF OC ON OUT_TAB FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_OC OUT_TAB.OC%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT OC into v_OC from ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID=:NEW.ORDER_ID and ORDER_SEQ=:NEW.ORDER_SEQ and rownum=1;
    IF :NEW.OC != v_OC and v_OC is not NULL THEN
      :NEW.OC:=v_OC;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

The trigger is intended to be executed in the following scenarios

1. INSERTION of a record in OUT_TAB OR
2. UPDATE OF the field OC ON OUT_TAB

Inside the Trigger Body the field OC itself is updated. Will that update invoke the trigger again (and recursively) for that matter?

Do i need to code it to avoid that recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it won't, this will be fine, when you set the value of :NEW.OC this is not actually updating the table, only once the trigger code completes is the table updated/inserted using the value you set :NEW.OC to